# in python how to get the document from the google fire store according to system time

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have my data in cloud fire store. its have different collection in it . in a collection the name of the document is the time(he format is hour:00) as you can see in the picture( attached ). I want to get the data of this document by round off the time is the same format

for example
the local time is 15:40 pm i want to round of the time as 15:00

so please let me know how to proceed  for such problem and if you have any reference please let me know

[fire store data base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuNGP.png)

right now what I'm getting is in the format( hour : minutes)
but I want the q(please check the code) is the format as **hour:00** so how I can round off the time as ( hour :00)

the code right now i have is

p = time.localtime()
q= time.strftime("%H:%M", p)

result = db.collection('TOU').document(q).get()

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret this correctly the question is actually about how to get the last full hour based on the current time.
You are nearly there, just replace the formatting specifier `%M` with `00`

```
q = time.strftime("%H:%M", p) # --> 13:59
```

to

```
q = time.strftime("%H:00", p) # --> 13:00
```

For future reference, please take some time to boil the question down to the actual core of what you are after, the info about the cloud fire store adds no value. Had you done so I'm pretty sure you would have discovered the solution on your own. And please format the code, it makes it way easier to read for the rest of us making us more likely to help you :)

If my answer works for you I would be happy if you mark it as the accepted solution.